# ReactNative: In the navigation bar on the right button, click the event does not Working, an error

Tags: swift, react-native

ReactNative:
I use **react-navigation** Component.

In the navigation bar on the right button, click the event is not Working

```
`_newCustomer() {
        alert('点击新建');
      }
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: '客户列表',
        headerRight: (
        <Button title={'添加客户'} onPress={this._newCustomer.bind(this)}/>
          ),
      }
```

The Error:

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this._newCustomer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're trying to call `this._newCustomer` from a static function, and `this` is undefined, because you're in a static function.

If you look at the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers) you'll see that in the examples they use anonymous functions. Do that, or call another static function instead.

Answer (score 1):

static navigationOptions does not have capability to link your dynamic 'this' variable. Normally you need to create a custom Button component and use this component to deal with click event.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerRight: (
      <EventButton
        navigation={navigation}
      />
    ),
  };
};
```

and then

```
export const EventButton = (props) => {
let testButton = <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('CreateNewCustomer',{ name: 'CreateNewCustomer'})}>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  return testButton 
}
```